# Updating json element

Tags: python, json

I am trying to do this code.

```
import urllib
import json
import requests

url = 'http://www.webiron.com/abuse_feed//?format=json'

response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data_json = json.loads(response.read())


for i in data_json:
    i['LogEvent'] = 'Trial'
    i['EvtLen'] = 213

print json.dumps(data_json,indent=6)
```

The Output i am getting is like following: pretty big output (showing part of output)

```
[
      {
            "incidents_reported": 3, 
            "attacker_ip": "178.137.88.8", 
            "event_time": "2018-05-15 19:30:09.832568-07", 
            "event_emails": [
                  "hostmaster@kyivstar.net", 
                  "abuse@kyivstar.net", 
                  "noc@kyivstar.net"
            ], 
            "entry_type": "report", 
            "EvtLen": 213, 
            "emails_deliverable": "Yes", 
            "LogEvent": "Trial", 
            "event_msg": "Fake Referrer Log SPAM Bot", 
            "days_unresolved": "<font color=\"green\"><3</font>"
      }, 
      {
            "incidents_reported": 52, 
            "attacker_ip": "221.229.166.171", 
            "event_time": "2018-05-15 19:29:45.039281-07", 
            "event_emails": [
                  "anti-spam@ns.chinanet.cn.net"
            ], 
            "entry_type": "report", 
            "EvtLen": 213, 
            "emails_deliverable": "No", 
            "LogEvent": "Trial", 
            "event_msg": "Abusive network connectivity", 
            "days_unresolved": "<font color=\"red\">3</font>"
      } ]
```

Now check element `days_unresolved : "<font color=\"red\">3</font>"` 
or `days_unresolved: "<font color=\"green\"><3</font>"`
is it possible to update or modify such element to simple 
`days_unresolved :  3` with other data?. This is how i want as a required output, is there some method or find such tag and remove it or iterate through entire data set and update it. is there any solution for this?

Comment: from `days_unresolved : "<font color=\"red\">3</font>"` this you want `3` as output or want to update in json data

Comment: update in json data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Regex to update `days_unresolved`

**Demo:**

```
import re
for i in data:
    if i.get("days_unresolved"):
        m = re.search('>(.*?)<', i["days_unresolved"])
        i["days_unresolved"] = m.group(1) if m else i["days_unresolved"]

print(data)
```

Comment: giving error
File "getpost.py", line 13, in <module>
    i["days_unresolved"] =  re.findall(r'>(.*?)<', i["days_unresolved"])[0]
KeyError: 'days_unresolved'

Comment: Updated snippet.Looks like the key `days_unresolved` is not in the JSON for some data.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot that worked! but can you help me to understand how did you figured out what to search and replace?

Comment: I am just using regex to search for content between `> <`. if it has valid data then replace the original content with the search returned content.

Answer (score 0):

Well BeautifulSoup bs4 could be used to scrape the HTML tags. Else a regular expression to identify the content between > and <

Comment: can you  give me some example ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HTMLParser` from `html.parser` (python3) or from `HTMLParser` (python3) - it's in the standard library, and therefore doesn't require you to install any additional packages:

```
try:
    from html.parser import HTMLParser
except ImportError:
    from HTMLParser import HTMLParser


class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
    strict = False
    convert_charrefs = True

    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.fed = []

    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.fed.append(data)

    def get_data(self):
        return ''.join(self.fed)

def strip_tags(html):
    s = MLStripper()
    s.feed(html)
    return s.get_data()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


source_code = """<span class="UserName"><a href="#">Martin Elias</a></span>"""



soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, HTML.parser)
```

print soup.a.string >>> 'Martin Elias'
Or 
print soup.text